# Migrate from PyQt4 to PyQt5

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt4

I using `PyQt4` and have this code:

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.process, QtCore.SIGNAL("finished(int,QProcess::ExitStatus)"), self.stop_run)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.picker, QtCore.SIGNAL("finished()"), self.get_picked_control)
        QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance().installEventFilter(QtCore.QAbstractEventDispatcher.instance())
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.action_record, QtCore.SIGNAL("triggered()"), self.record)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.action_stop, QtCore.SIGNAL("triggered()"), self.stop_record)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.action_picker, QtCore.SIGNAL("triggered()"), self.pick_control)
```

But, when I upgrade to `PyQq5` I get error:

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.process, QtCore.SIGNAL("finished(int,QProcess::ExitStatus)"), self.stop_run)
AttributeError: type object 'QObject' has no attribute 'connect'
```

How change this lines for work with `PyQt5`?

Comment: see https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/pyqt4_differences.html

Comment: use 1) `self.process.finished.connect(self.stop_run)` and `@QtCore.pyqtSlot(int, QtCore.QProcess.ExitStatus) def stop_run(self, exitCode, exitStatus):`

Comment: 2) `self.picker.finished.connect(self.get_picked_control)`

Comment: 3) `self.ui.action_record.triggered.connect(self.record)` 4) `self.ui.action_stop.triggered.connect(self.stop_record)` 5) `self.ui.action_picker.triggered.connect(self.pick_control)`